# Which web hosting company is best for Magento 2 Ecommerce development

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, hosting

For the 1st time ,I build eCommerce website using Magento2 open-source.

Please help!

Which **web hosting company is best for Magento 2 eCommerce development**

Comment: you need this for live shop with continuous development, or just to develop sites and show off for customers??

Answer (score 1):

Quite honestly there's not many hosting providers that are listing Development hosting as one of their services (They'll likely be able to provide something if you inquire about it though)

For this reason it's difficult to pinpoint the "best" Magento 2 Development Hosting providers. Before you make a decision it might be worth reading this blog post by Aheadworks who mention a few hosting providers as well as requirements for Magento 2 so you know roughly what you're looking for. Blog post [here](https://blog.aheadworks.com/choose-the-best-magento-2-hosting/).

Another couple of hosting providers worth mentioning:

- MageMojo - https://magemojo.com/
- Sonassi - https://www.sonassi.com/
- MageOptimised - https://mageoptimised.com/ *(I have to mention that I work for/am affiliated with this hosting provider)*

If you want to get your hands dirty then I would also suggest looking into a Digital Ocean droplet to host your own Development environment off, it could be a lot cheaper in the long run but you won't have the same kind of support. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are many hosting companies but Rackspace and Nexcess  are best

**Rackspace** is a dedicated Magento hosting provider with the biggest number of Magento certified developers among other official hosting partners. The company is positioned as a #1 hosting provider for Magento applications. Employs 8 Magento certified developers. Offices in the U.S.,the UK and Australia.

**Nexcess** is the oldest Magento hosting provider ensuring Magento optimized hosting in the U.S., United Kingdom, Netherlands and Australia.

Comment: hm, running live site and development - are two different things. the question is more about development, not about your favorite brand names...

Comment: Rackspace laid off their Magento Managed Support staff back in February. https://franciskim.co/rackspace-dropping-support-magento-mean/

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is not officially supported, but I use Windows VMs in Azure, and their performance has been very good. I have not had more than 1 or 2 issues because I am using Windows with IIS and generally the stability of it has been surprisingly good. So if you have other Windows related hardware I would strongly suggest looking at this.

You could also use Linux VMs in Azure which would be equally very good. They have a large number of DCs now, depending where you need to hold you data geographically.